# Need support on using git-sync and persistent volumes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to use git-sync to write data from a gitlab repo to a persistent volume, then pull that data into another pod (trim_load) and perform a job. Here are the manifests I have set up. I am new to this and developing locally, and I could use all the direction I can get!

I am getting an error that the directory doesn't exist, but it does on my local machine, but not on the kind cluster that I am using. How do I create a directory on the kind cluster?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dbt-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /Users/my_user/k8s/pv1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - kind-control-plane
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dbt-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeName: dbt-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gitsync-sidecar
spec:
  containers:
    - name: git-sync
      # This container pulls git data and publishes it into volume
      # "content-from-git".  In that volume you will find a symlink
      # "current" (see -dest below) which points to a checked-out copy of
      # the master branch (see -branch) of the repo (see -repo).
      # NOTE: git-sync already runs as non-root.
      image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync/git-sync:v3.3.4
      args:
        - --repo= <the git repo I wanna copy HTTPS link>
        - --branch=master
        - --depth=1
        - --period=60
        - --link=current
        - --root=/git # I don't know what this means
      volumeMounts:
        - name: dbt-pv
          mountPath: /git # I don't know what this means
  volumes:
  - name: dbt-pv
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dbt-pvc
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: trim-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: trim-pod-cont
    image: <my docker container to run the code>
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dbt-pv
      mountPath: /tmp/dbt
  volumes:
    - name: dbt-pv
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: dbt-pvc
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with kind, but from what i gather on their website, it works like minikube. Which means your cluster is inside a container itself.

The folder on your local machine exists, but your volume is looking for a folder inside the host machine, which is the container running your cluster.

You have to open a shell in your cluster container and create the folder there.

If you want to access this folder on your local machine, you then have to mount your local folder in your kind cluster.